# Lightwidget is not working in my HTTPS website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, instagram

lightwidget is not working in my HTTP website. It is working locally when I add `http:` to the `src` but not working with `https:`

```
<iframe src="http://lightwidget.com/widgets/f4d013e66d115f799ddf8b58a43a422e.html" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true" class="lightwidget-widget" style="width:100%;border:0;overflow:hidden;"></iframe>

<iframe src="//lightwidget.com/widgets/f4d013e66d115f799ddf8b58a43a422e.html" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true" class="lightwidget-widget" style="width:100%;border:0;overflow:hidden;"></iframe>

<iframe src="https://www.lightwidget.com/widgets/f4d013e66d115f799ddf8b58a43a422e.html" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true" class="lightwidget-widget" style="width:100%;border:0;overflow:hidden;"></iframe>
```

Comment: <iframe src="//lightwidget.com/widgets/f4d013e66d115f799ddf8b58a43a422e.html" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true" class="lightwidget-widget" style="width:100%;border:0;overflow:hidden;"></iframe>

Comment: What's the relevance of the three `iframe` elements? Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: 1. working in local file  2. working in http: not working in https:   3. showing the error, don't work on https:

Comment: what's the exact error ? anyway. in under 10 seconds of google search i found on the `LightWidget` website that : `Do You support HTTPS ?

Yes, we do, but it’s supported only in upgraded widgets.` So, do you have the upgraded  version ? if no, then that's your answer.

Comment: `https://lightwidget.com/widgets/f4d013e66d115f799ddf8b58a43a422e.html` - "This is free version of our widget. HTTPS is disabled for free widgets. Please upgrade this widget to enable HTTPS on your awesome website!". It's by design. BTW `3. showing the error, don't work on https:` <- please do not paraphrase error messages (if there was an error message).